# Amazon Web Services - how to run a script daily

Tags: r, amazon-web-services

I have an R script that I run every day that scrapes data from a couple of different websites, and then writes the data scraped to a couple of different CSV files. Each day, at a specific time (that changes daily) I open RStudio, open the file, and run the script. I check that it runs correctly each time, and then I save the output to a CSV file. It is often a pain to have to do this everyday (takes ~10-15 minutes a day). I would love it if someway I could have this script run automatically at a pre-defined specific time, and a buddy of mine said AWS is capable of doing this?

Is this true? If so, what is the specific feature / aspect of AWS that is able to do this, this way I can look more into it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two options come to mind thinking about this:

- Host a EC2 Instance with **R** on it and configure a CRON-Job to execute your R-Script regularly.
  One easy way to get started: Use [this](http://www.louisaslett.com/RStudio_AMI/) AMI.
  To execute the script R offers a CLI `rscript`. See e.g. [here](https://tgmstat.wordpress.com/2013/09/11/schedule-rscript-with-cron/) on how to set this up
- Go Serverless: AWS Lambda is a hosted microservice. Currently **R** is not natively supported but on the official AWS Blog [here](https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/compute/analyzing-genomics-data-at-scale-using-r-aws-lambda-and-amazon-api-gateway/) they offer a step by step guid on how to run R. Basically you execute **R** from Python using the [`rpy2`](https://rpy2.readthedocs.io/en/version_2.8.x/)-Package.
  Once you have this setup schedule the function via CloudWatch Events (~hosted cron-job). [Here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html) you can find a step by step guide on how to do that.
  One more thing: You say that your function outputs CSV files: To save them properly you will need to put them to a file-storage like AWS-S3. You can do this i R via the [aws.s3](https://github.com/cloudyr/aws.s3)-package. Another option would be to use the [AWS SDK for python](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which is preinstalled in the lambda-function. You could e.g. write a csv file to the `/tmp/`-dir and after the **R** script is done move the file to S3 via [boto3's S3 upload_file function](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_file).

IMHO the first option is easier to setup but the second-one is more robust.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit counterintuitive but you'd use Cloudwatch with an event rule to run periodically.  It can run a Lambda or send a message to an SNS topic or SQS queue.  The challenge you'll have is that a Lambda doesn't support R so you'd either have to have a Lambda kick off something else or have something waiting on the SNS topic or SQS queue to run the script for you.  It isn't a perfect solution as there are, potentially, quite a few moving parts.

Comment: Would anyone like to tell me why this was down voted?

Comment: I thought it was helpful, thanks. I am going to try first with Floo0's first suggestion hosting an EC2 instance, but both of you suggested this as well and I may try.

Answer (score 1):

@stdunbar is right about using CloudWatch Events to trigger a lambda function. You can set a frequency of the trigger or use a Cron. But as he mentioned, Lambda does not natively support R.

This may help you to use R with Lambda: [R Statistics ready to run in AWS Lambda and x86_64 Linux VMs](http://nafiux.github.io/portableR/)

Comment: Not sure this is going to work as `portableR` is not supporting `curl` as of now... Now sure which scraper @Canovice uses...

Comment: I use rselenium and rvest to scrape. are both of those okay with an EC2 instance, the first suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running windows, one of the easier solution is to write a .BAT script to run your R-script and then use Window's task scheduler to run as desired.

To call your R-script from your batch file use the following syntax:

```
C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.4\bin\Rscript.exe" C:\rscripts\hello.R
```

Just verify the path to the "RScript" application and your R code is correct.

Answer (score 0):

1. Dockerize your script (write a Dockerfile, build an image)
2. Push the image to AWS ECR
3. Create an AWS ECS cluster and AWS ECS task definition within the cluster that will run the image from AWS ECR every time it's spun-up
4. Use EventBridge to create a time-based trigger that will run the AWS ECS task definition

I recently gave a seminar walking through this at the Why R? 2022 conference.

- You can check out the video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dgkm0QkWXag
- And the GitHub repo here: https://github.com/mrismailt/why-r-2022-serverless-r-in-the-cloud