# In R, how can I schedule function execution in a cronjob-like way?

Tags: r, loops, timer, scheduled-tasks

I would like to write an R script that runs for the whole day. It should basically be an infinite loop that fetches trading data, applies smart stuff to it, and uploads the trading data somewhere else again.

I'm thinking about starting the script at 8:30am, then it would automatically "do nothing" until 9:00am, then start running in a loop until 5:00pm, and then idle again, until I shut down the R session.

What's the best way to achieve this behavior?

I have no access to Linux machines, so multiple scripts and cronjobs are not possible, unfortunately.

Comment: do you have access to Powershell?

Comment: meatspace: Not yet, but we can certainly ask to have it installed.

Comment: This might be helpful as well: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41948186/3301344

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 while ( as.numeric(format(Sys.time(),format =  "%H")) %in% 8:17){
if(as.numeric(format(Sys.time(),format =  "%H")) %in% 9:17){ 
# your code here
}
}
```

Comment: Haha, simple and beautiful. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793389/scheduling-r-script)

Windows Task scheduler can do the task

Even with [Rstudio](https://www.r-bloggers.com/new-rstudio-add-in-to-schedule-r-scripts/) you can
Some more [links](https://nerdsrule.co/2013/09/03/scheduling-r-tasks-with-crontab-to-conserve-memory/) here and here [Link](https://tgmstat.wordpress.com/2013/09/11/schedule-rscript-with-cron/)
Then the package `taskschedulR`

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a Windows consumer platform, you could use the 'scheduleR' package. Otherwise, if you're on a Windows Server, then you could use the Windows Scheduler.